# Docker image with gpu gives error 535.129.3 does not match DSO version 545.23.6

Tags: docker, tensorflow, cuda

I though a docker image wit GPU support would solve my problems with installing cuda.
I have run:

```
 docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
 docker run --gpus all -it --rm -p 8889:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter
```

but when checking if the jupyter server has GPU support it gives me the errors:

```
I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:274] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_COMPAT_NOT_SUPPORTED_ON_DEVICE: forward compatibility was attempted on non supported HW
I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:129] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: 0e940b862ceb
I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:136] hostname: 0e940b862ceb
I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:159] libcuda reported version is: 545.23.6
I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:163] kernel reported version is: 535.129.3
E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:244] kernel version 535.129.3 does not match DSO version 545.23.6 -- cannot find working devices in this configuration
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar output/problem.
Are you trying to run docker on a rtx 40xx card? (I'm trying to run on a rtx 4060 ti 16Gb).

After a while I have tried to run, instead of the last version, the previous one, right now: docker run --gpus all -it tensorflow/tensorflow:2.14.0-gpu python.

It gives me some errors when loading, but it seems to work well training models with GPU (quick test right now, I will a long test right now)

Comment: rtx 3090. Ive also tried to install cuda locally with older vesions like cuda 12.2, 11.8, 11.5 - but the last step is always "sudo apt-get install cuda" which installs the latest cuda, which is currently cuda-12.3. Its so stupid. There are so many people that similarly complain about installing cuda. Why cant the people at nvidia fix it. Its not like theyr product isnt popular. Perphaps they want to raise the bar to entry - haha.

Comment: Thank you. I tried making an issue for this on TF Github but there was an obligatory field for reproducible code so I figured I should just stop using Tensorflow. Like 535.154.05 is the most recent NVIDIA driver on Linux so I don't think there's anything I can do.

Comment: Why does it require several installations to get the GPU working with tensorflow or pytorch. Why cant NVIDIA provide a bundle that detects which python version and which gpu the user has, and does the appropriate installations. It should be scriptable.